# rewrite rule nginx for everything in a domain

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'd like to make a rewrite of my domain `name.domain.tld` to another URL. I managed to do this but if I type `name.domain.tld/dashboard` or anything after the tld I still get the content like without the rule.

In the config I have `rewrite ^/$ https://new.url redirect;`

So how can I do a redirect no matter what is being typed in after `name.domain.tld`?

Comment: Do you want to preserve an existing request URI (making `name.domain.tld/dashboard` redirected to `new.domain.tld/dashboard`) or redirect every request to the `new.domain.tld/`?

Comment: No. The original URL is something totally different. Like `old.url` or `old.url/dashboard` but I want people to be redirected to `new.url` if they type in `old.url/$` so no matter what subdir of `old.url` they use.

Comment: What is that `new.url` in your rewrite rule? Where is the domain name in it? What do you mean by `old.url/$`? Do you mean you want to rewrite URIs ending with a dollar sign? Please, make your question more clarified.

Comment: The $ is just a wildcard. So I want URL A (the old one) to be redireted to URL B no matter what subdirectory the person using URL A is using. With what I have the redirect only works when no subdirs are being used.

Comment: So you want to redirect an URL within the same domain? You do not change the domain with redirection?

Comment: No. As I said. The old URL ist something like `old.url` and may have some subdirs and I want ALL requests that are being made to the old url no matter if a subdir is given or not redirected to a total different URL that has nothing to do whatsoever with the old URL.

Comment: Ok, it is that `https://new.url` that confused me. You can use a redirect address in a form `<scheme>://domain/url` or simply `url` but not the `<scheme>://url`. You are using `^` start-of-the-string anchor and `$` end-of-the-string anchor making your `^/$` regex matching only the root `/` request and nothing else. Use `rewrite ^ /new/url;` to match any request (any string has a beginning, yeah?)

Comment: That did it. Thank you!